# Get only common elements based on a property in array of object

Tags: javascript, typescript

I make an API call and I retrieve some data in Json. the JSON looks like this. Here is the input:

```
[
    {
        "CategoryID": "1"
        "CategoryName": "cat1"
        "Indexes": [
            { "IndexID" : "1", IndexName: "name1"},
            { "IndexID" : "2", IndexName: "name2"},
            { "IndexID" : "3", IndexName: "name3"},
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "CategoryID": "2"
        "CategoryName": "cat1"
        "Indexes": [
            { "IndexID" : "4", IndexName: "name4"},
            { "IndexID" : "5", IndexName: "name2"},
            { "IndexID" : "6", IndexName: "name3"},
        ]
    },
    {
        "CategoryID": "1"
        "CategoryName": "cat1"
        "Indexes": [
            { "IndexID" : "7", IndexName: "name7"},
            { "IndexID" : "8", IndexName: "name2"},
            { "IndexID" : "8", IndexName: "name3"},
        ]
    }
]
```

I have this ouput :

```
[
    { "IndexID" : "1", IndexName: "name1"},
    { "IndexID" : "2", IndexName: "name2"},
    { "IndexID" : "3", IndexName: "name3"},
    { "IndexID" : "4", IndexName: "name4"},
    { "IndexID" : "5", IndexName: "name2"},
    { "IndexID" : "6", IndexName: "name3"},
    { "IndexID" : "7", IndexName: "name7"},
    { "IndexID" : "8", IndexName: "name2"},
    { "IndexID" : "8", IndexName: "name3"},
]
```

I should have :

```
[
    { "IndexID" : "2", IndexName: "name2"},
    { "IndexID" : "3", IndexName: "name3"}
]
```

The indexName name2 and name3 is present in all the 3 categories selected.

CategoryModel and IndexModel are interfaces that I use to 'map' my json to object. Here is a sample of the IndexModel:

```
export interface IndexModel {
  IndexID: number;
  IndexName: string;
  ...
  Required: string;
  DataType: string;
}
```

I retrieve the data in a method that aims to build the list:

```
buildIndexList(): void {
  console.log('# buildIndexList() called');
  // console.log(JSON.stringify(this.selectedCategories));
  const indexesClone = [...this.indexes];
  for (const category of this.selectedCategories) {
    console.log('Category : ', category);
    for (const index of category.Indexes) {
      this.indexes.push(index);
    }
  }
  // this.filteredIndexes = [ ...new Map(this.indexes.map(item => [item['IndexName'], item])).values() ];
  this.filteredIndexes = this.getCommonsElements(this.indexes, indexesClone);
  console.log('Filtered values : ', this.filteredIndexes);
}

getCommonsElements(arr1: IndexModel[], arr2: IndexModel[]): IndexModel[]  {
  const res: IndexModel[] = [];
  if (arr2.length === 0) {
    arr1.forEach(el1 => {
      res.push(el1);
    });
  } else {
    arr1.forEach(el1 => {
      arr2.forEach(el2 => {
        if (el1.IndexName === el2.IndexName) {
          res.push(el1);
        }
      });
    });
  }
  return res;
}
```

The code wouldn't be so complex if i had to filter identical objects. My issue is that objects are identical based on their IndexName (non sense but it's my use case).

For example, I shoud retrieve names: name2 and name3 if i select category 1 and 2. I must not have duplicate and i must get the intersection of the indexes.

Comment: Can you please provide a sample input and output? It's unclear what you're asking for. Also, please provide a definition for the `IndexModel` type so we can reproduce it.

Comment: the IndexModel is just an interface to map my object. I added a sample of this interface. I also updated my question with sample of what i would expect.

Comment: Why are the IndexIDs 2 and 3? Do you just want the index IDs from `arr1` and just discard the ones from `arr2`?

Comment: Learn about `filter`.

Comment: @Aplet123 it's just because I only want the values that are common to all categories. If a category has index1, index2, index3 and a second category has index3, I want to return only index3...

Comment: @AluanHaddad i'm actually looking at this right now. thx